# php with R script connected to database

Tags: php, sql, r, database

From php code I run r script, where I connect to database to get data:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                      host = "localhost",
                      user = "user",
                      dbname = "myDatabase",
                      password = "password")

data <- data.frame(tbl(con, "data"))
```

This r script I run every second. Problem is that each time I have to connect to database again - cost lot of time. It is possible to be connected before I start r script or somehow send connection from php?

Answer (score 0):

How about connecting in R after every 1000 iterations? You can obviously increase/decrease 1000 value as per your preference.

```
if(!exists('i')) i <- 0

if(i %% 1000 == 0) {
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                        host = "localhost",
                        user = "user",
                        dbname = "myDatabase",
                        password = "password")
}
i <- i + 1
data <- data.frame(tbl(con, "data"))
```